# Djkstras Algorithm in Java

Tags: java, dijkstra

I am writing a program that has to print out the shortest distance between each node in the graph. It also needs to print out the last hop (the hop it went through to get the shortest path). Having a hard time figuring how to find the previous node. Here is the code below:

```
public class Graph {

    private Node[] nodes;

    public Node[] getNodes() {
        return nodes;
    }

    private int noOfNodes;

    public int getNoOfNodes() {
        return noOfNodes;
    }

    private Edge[] edges;

    public Edge[] getEdges() {
        return edges;
    }

    private int noOfEdges;

    public int getNoOfEdges() {
        return noOfEdges;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor that builds the whole graph from an Array of Edges
     */
    public Graph(Edge[] edges){

        // The edges are passed in, so store them
        this.edges = edges;

        // Create all the nodes, ready to be updated with the edges
        this.noOfNodes = calculateNoOfNodes(edges);
        this.nodes = new Node[this.noOfNodes];
        for (int n = 0; n < this.noOfNodes; n++) {
            this.nodes[n] = new Node();
        }       

        // Add all the edges to the nodes. Each edge is added to 2 nodes (the "to" and the "from")
        this.noOfEdges = edges.length;
        //while(edges.length-1 < edges.length){
            for (int edgeToAdd = 0; edgeToAdd < this.noOfEdges; edgeToAdd++) {
                this.nodes[edges[edgeToAdd].getFromNodeIndex()].getEdges().add(edges[edgeToAdd]);
                this.nodes[edges[edgeToAdd].getToNodeIndex()].getEdges().add(edges[edgeToAdd]);
            }
       // }
    }

    /**
     * Calculate the number of nodes in an array of edges
     * 
     * @param edges An array of edges that represents the graph.
     * @return The number of nodes in the graph.
     *
     */
    private int calculateNoOfNodes(Edge[] edges) {
        int noOfNodes = 0;
        for (Edge e:edges ) {
           // if(e != null){
                if (e.getToNodeIndex() > noOfNodes) noOfNodes = e.getToNodeIndex();
                if (e.getFromNodeIndex() > noOfNodes) noOfNodes = e.getFromNodeIndex();
           // }
        }
        noOfNodes++;    
        return noOfNodes;       
    }
    //private int [] hopNode;
    private int hop;
    /**
     * Uses Dijkstra's algorithm to calculate the shortest distance from the source to all nodes
     * 
     */
    public void calculateShortestDistances(){
        // Set node 2 as the source
        this.nodes[2].setDistanceFromSource(0); // sorce based on 2
        int nextNode = 2; // set

        // Visit every node, in order of stored distance
        for (int i = 0; i < this.nodes.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("i:" + i);
            // Loop round the edges that are joined to the current node
            ArrayList<Edge> currentNodeEdges = this.nodes[nextNode].getEdges();
            System.out.println ( "currentNodeEdges: " + currentNodeEdges.toString()); 
            for (int joinedEdge = 0; joinedEdge < currentNodeEdges.size(); joinedEdge++) {

                // Determine the joined edge neighbor of the current node
                int neighborIndex = currentNodeEdges.get(joinedEdge).getneighborIndex(nextNode);
                System.out.println(" neighborIndex: " +  neighborIndex);
                // Only interested in an unvisited neighbor
                if (!this.nodes[neighborIndex].isVisited()) {

                    // Calculate the tentative distance for the neighbor
                    int tentative = this.nodes[nextNode].getDistanceFromSource() + currentNodeEdges.get(joinedEdge).getLength();

                    // Overwrite if the tentative distance is less than what's currently stored
                    if (tentative < nodes[neighborIndex].getDistanceFromSource()) {
                        nodes[neighborIndex].setDistanceFromSource(tentative);
                        //System.out.println ("tentative: "+tentative);
                        // hop= currentNodeEdges.get(tentative).getneighborIndex(nextNode);
                        //System.out.println("hop:" +hop); 
                    }

                }
                //System.out.println("neighborIndex[joinedEdge]:"+neighborIndex);
            }
            //hopNode[i] = neighborIndex; 
            // All neighbors are checked so this node is now visited

            nodes[nextNode].setVisited(true);
            // neighbors[i] = neighborIndex;
            // The next node to visit must be the one with the shortest distance.
            nextNode = getNodeShortestDistanced();

            hop= nextNode;
            System.out.println(hop);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Scans the unvisited nodes and calculates which one has the shortest distance from the source.
     * 
     * @return The index of the node with the smallest distance
     */
    private int getNodeShortestDistanced() {

        int storedNodeIndex = 0;
        int storedDist = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        for (int i = 0; i < this.nodes.length; i++) {
            int currentDist = this.nodes[i].getDistanceFromSource();
            if (!this.nodes[i].isVisited() && currentDist < storedDist) {
                storedDist = currentDist;
                storedNodeIndex = i;

            }

        }

        return storedNodeIndex;
    }
    //public int findNeighbor(int node){
    //   int hop; 
    // hop = getneighborIndex(node); 
    //return hop;
    //}
    /**
     * Overrides Object.toString() to show the contents of the graph
     * 
     */
    public String toString() {

        String output = "Number of nodes = " + this.noOfNodes;
        output += "\nNumber of edges = " + this.noOfEdges;
        int sourceNode = 2;



        for (int i = 0; i < this.nodes.length; i++) {
            output += ("\nThe shortest distance from node "+ sourceNode + " to node " + i + " is " + nodes[i].getDistanceFromSource() +" and the hop is "+ hop+ "." ); //" and the hop node is "+hop+ "." );
        }

        return output;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library, instead of create your own class:

http://jgrapht.org/javadoc/org/jgrapht/alg/DijkstraShortestPath.html